# Uploading a file to storage on Azure using cmdets

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to upload an image to Azure storage using powershell. Reading [their documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156055.aspx) it dosent seem to be supported (i cant find a reference to how to do it). It seems like a fairly core bit of functionality, have a missed something? Can anyone link me to an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As opposed to the current cmdlets, the 'retired' Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets project did supported operations on blob storage:

- `Add-Blob`: Uploads a blob to the specified container in Windows Azure blob storage.
- `Clear-Container`: Removes blobs from one or more containers in Windows Azure blob storage.
- `Get-Container`: Gets the blob containers in the specified storage account.
- `Save-Container`: Downloads blobs from one or more containers in Windows Azure blob storage and saves them to local disk.

It's still available for download [on CodePlex](http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/releases/view/84058).

Comment: +1.  You can also roll your own fairly easily since PS has full access to .NET (meaning you have full access to StorageClient).  See example in David's script here:  http://www.davidaiken.com/2011/10/26/how-to-clean-up-old-windows-azure-diagnostics/

Answer (score 6):

There is a **Set-AzureStorageBlobContent** cmd in windows azure powershell.

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container upload -File .\filename -Blob blobname
```

For details, please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408487.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, the supported [Windows Azure Powershell download](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/?fb=en-us) now has blob commandlets.

Here's a [walkthrough of doing an async parallel blob upload](http://michaelwasham.com/2013/03/27/windows-azure-powershell-cmdlets-now-supports-storage/).

But really you want to install Windows Azure Powershell and then `man blob`